# Hugo change layout

Tags: hugo

I have a following structure in my Hugo & Doks project:

```
 - content 
   - docs
      - working.md
      - working-as-well.md
   - get-started2
      - working.md
      ...
   - get-started.md
...
  - layouts
    - get-started2
      - single.html
    - get-started.html
```

Content placed in `docs` and `get-started2` has customized layout and works as expected. Great!

However, I have huge pain to set-up custom layout for `get-started.md`. I cannot do it like with `get-started2` - place it into a folder. Client requests to have get started URL as:

`www.SomeProject.com/get-started`

so it must not be placed in folder (like `get-started2`)

`www.SomeProject.com/get-started2/working`

Do you have any hints please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have at least three options:

Use front matter to set the "type":

In `content/get-started.md` set `type: mytype` in front matter.

The layout will be located at (for example) `layout/mytype/single.html`.

---

Use front matter to set the "layout":

In `content/get-started.md` set `layout: mylayout` in front matter.

The layout will be located at (for example) `layout/_default/mylayout.html`

---

Or use a subdirectory, but make it the section index:

The file is located at `content/get-started/_index.md`

The layout will be located at (for example) `layout/get-started/list.html`

Notice that the template name has changed from "single" to "list", but you can still write your layout in exactly the same way.

---

I use "(for example)" because Hugo has an [enormous list](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/) of directories/filenames it searches through to find its templates, and if an earlier matching template is found, the custom layout gets ignored.

Comment: I did [the tutorial](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/#step-4-add-some-content) and the folder `layouts` was created and theme is `ananke`. How can I use frontmatter with `layout: test`? Easier would be to remove the theme? Can you adapt your answer to include an example related to the tutorial?

Comment: I've been using hugo for 2 years and I wasn't clear on the above - very much appreciated Richard.

Comment: If the content: content/global/en.md what are the layouts for it only for this node?